# Is hierarchial a word?

Tags: orthography

I've found one reference that says [hierarchial](https://www.wordnik.com/words/hierarchial) is an alternative form of hierarchical, but it's an unreferenced resource.  Some wiseacre wrote a bug fix for my software saying hierarchical was the only spelling of the word and I'd like to prove said wiseacre wrong. So, can someone crack open the Oxford English Dictionary with the tiny print and help me out?

Comment: The online OED does not have _hierarchial_ either as an entry or as an alternative spelling. It does however have _hierarchal_, with no cross-reference between that and _hierarchical_.

Answer (score 4):

Neither Oxford Dictionaries nor the OED has an entry for *hierarchial*, but the OED does have entries for *hierarchal* and *hierarchic* as well as *hierarchical*. This, however, is not to say that *hierarchial* doesn’t exist.

Answer (score 2):

Between "a word" and "not a word" is a no-man's-land where the casualties of past flame wars lie bleeding.

That said, your proposed variant is wobbling on two weak legs, not only is the *-ial* unusual here at best, but the *heir-* is generally considered a typo when it happens.

You might be able to show it meets the condition of at least having some use, but it wouldn't be advisable to use.

For that matter, I **can** find *jerarchy, jerarchye, cherarchy, ierarche* each mentioned in the OED as having been forms used for *hierarchy*, but that doesn't make any of them spellings to use in most modern contexts.

Comment: yeah, the most annoying part about the word (whether or not it ever existed in medical terminology) is that it appears to have been removed from government websites probably by some gigantic spell checker in the sky.  It was used, and appears to be copied from US Government sources in our source code hundreds of times, but is no longer found on cms.gov.

Answer (score 1):

Wiktionary lists [hierarchial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hierarchial) as an alternative form of hierarchical. (NB spelling)

Google tries to correct to hierarchical, though.

Interestingly, the [NIH](http://oalm.od.nih.gov/hierarchial-structure) (which should *particularly* know the difference between hierarchical and hierarchial) lists their "Office of Acquisition and Logistics Management" **Hierarchial** Structure. This might be more common in the [Sciences](http://www.ask.com/question/what-is-a-hierarchial-structure) and technology.

> *Hierarchial* taxonomy terms should not be unique on different parents.
>   You can perform a *Hierarchial* Run to solve your model for multiple objectives simultaneously. (IBM)
>   *Hierarchial* Coassembly of a Cyanine Dye in Poly(vinyl alcohol) Fibrous Films by Electrospinning (ACS Journals)
>   *Hierarchial Task Analysis* (book by) Andrew Shepherd

Comment: So, perhaps a medical records program might be more likely to use the spelling "Heirarchial" than something to do with Military or Religious power structures?

Comment: Yes, I would agree with that, although hierarchical would still be more common.

Comment: The fact that it appears only in Wiktionary confirms my opinion that it is the best place to go for misspelled words.